# Get data in .csv format from php form

Tags: php, csv

I'm using below code to get data from PHP form. Its working fine.

```html
 <?php

$email=$_POST['email'];
$name=$_POST['name'];
$designation=$_POST['designation'];
$company=$_POST['company'];
$phone=$_POST['phone'];
$data=$name.",".$email.",".$designation.",".$company.",".$phone;

$file="file.csv";


file_put_contents($file, $data . PHP_EOL, FILE_APPEND);


?>
```

Whenever any user puts information in the form with separated (.) then name and email come in different cells in .csv file.

below is issue/csv image
[image]

How it will solved?

Thanks!

Comment: just build an array of the values, then use [fputcsv()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fputcsv.php); PHP's built-in csv writer function, that knows how to handle a separator in the values

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use PHP's [`fputcsv`](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.fputcsv.php). Let it handle the particulars of CSV formatting for you!

```
<?php

$email       = $_POST['email'];
$name        = $_POST['name'];
$designation = $_POST['designation'];
$company     = $_POST['company'];
$phone       = $_POST['phone'];

$data = [
         $name,
         $email,
         $designation,
         $company,
         $phone,
];

$file = fopen('file.csv', 'a'); // Append data to end of file.

fputcsv($file, $data);
```

If you need a delimiter other than the default (`,`) put that for the third argument. Same for enclosure & escape chars (`"`, `\`) as 4th and 5th args.

Comment: Thanks @Cameron Hurd